# How to add new line to a cell so that new data is appended to previous data on a new line

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop in which a cell is getting overwritten.

The cell lets say contain text `xxx` at one particular counter. In the next counter it gets over written by `yyy`. I can only see `yyy` in the end as the cell gets overwritten. What I want to do is preserve the original `xxx` and have the `yyy` on a next line in the same cell. Just like one enters data manually by pushing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Can anyone help me identify the correct syntax for this code logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Range("A1").Value = CStr(Range("A1").Value) + Chr(10) + "yyy"
```

`CStr` makes sure, that a possible numeric value of (in this example) A1 is cast to string, otherwise the + operator might fail.

`Chr(10)` takes care of appending a line break. `"yyy"` of course is your new text. If this text happens to be a numeric value aswell, use `CStr(yyy)`.